# What is the difference between "which" and "in which"?

Tags: relative-pronouns

I always confuse these both. When should we actually use them in a sentence?

Comment: Add some research you have for it. Use some examples and tell us what do you think about them. Or else, this question may attract closing votes of 'too broad'.

Comment: Never mind then. Every question I ask here gets closed anyway. lol . Close this one too

Comment: I think this question is fine, i had it too when i was young. Sometimes i think asking question is too difficult here, discouraging people who dare to ask.

Comment: No, it's not so. Questions that lack details or research are likely to get closed. The reason is without them, it becomes broad, primarily opinion based (especially for questions without any context), or it may not be precisely addressing your concern.

Comment: This isn't about "closing just for the sake of closing", but simply to understand your question better. We might give a very lengthy and elaborate answer - which doesn't help you at all. So please accept that we sometimes ask before answering. The more details *you* give us, the better can *we* help you. (And I disagree with @MaulikV in judging this as "too broad". "Lack of details", perhaps, for the reasons I just explained.)

Comment: @john, it is best if you provide an example yourself. That way we can help you better. Only if we understand the question fully, can we help you with the correct solution, right ? We are here to help each other out and none of of us wouldn't want to give you a vague or wrong answer. All right ? Don't get offended mate, we just want to help. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

*"Which"* in this sense is a word for building up a relative clause, for example:

> "John brought me a car, which is my favorite."

The word *"in"* is not part of this unit, rather it belongs to another unit in a sentence, for example:

> "John brought me a car, in which I found my computer."

This is equivalent to saying *"I found my computer in a car. John brought me the car."* Therefore the word *"in"* is a preposition linking *"computer"* and *"car"*. In cases like this, we put *"in"* before *"which"*.

One more complicated example,

> "John brought me a car, the price of which surprised me."

It means *"The price of the car surprised me."*

Comment: +1 - Good work using an example to help the OP understand. I'm sure he found it useful.